# Authentication failure upgrading FedEx RateService wsdl

Tags: php, soap, fedex

We were seeing some 9004 errors coming back via the FedEx Soap RateService API and while I was investigating the cause, I noticed we were still using v9 of the WSDL file and they are currently running on v24.

I upgraded the WSDL file then regenerated the php class objects but now I am getting an 'Authentication Failed' error 1000 using the same credentials that work without such an error under v9 of the WSDL.

I sent an inquiry to FedEx support but I'm wondering if anyone has run into this before that can help key me in on other things to look for.

SW

Comment: face the same problem. have you solved it?

Comment: I never got a response back from them